# Can EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel be used to select files in hidden folders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Editor tool in which I would like to select files that are stored in `Application.persistentDataPath`, however that is a hidden folder, and the file browser opened by `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel` cannot see that folder.

If there a way to get `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel` to display hidden folders? Or is there an alternative way to browse to those locations from an `EditorWindow`?

Unity's documentation for both `OpenFilePanel` and `OpenFilePanelWithFilters` are both sparse and don't answer this question.

Comment: afaik this totally depends on your OS FileBrowser settings .. Unity is just using your OS native filebrowser .. so if those are not enabled in e.g. your windows settings I suppose they will also no show up here and wise versa - not Unity specific ;)

Comment: I was hoping that would be the case, but in MacOS my finder settings show hidden files and folders, but from the browser opened by my EditorWindow those aren't visible. I did find somewhat of a workaround for my specific case, but opening the prompt within the hidden folder I was going go browse to.

Comment: ah ok that's weird ... only on Windows and here it is as I said above .. the behavior basically depends on the settings of the Windows File explorer - sounds a bit like there is an additional API in the MacOS finder which Unity either didn't have in mind or ignored ^^